# Load and SQL Query DynamoDB Map data type in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I have this item in DynamoDB, it contains a Map attribute:

```
{
  "orgName": {
    "S": "example"
  },
  "typeSavings": {
    "M": {
      "TELECOMS": {
        "N": "50"
      },
      "GAS": {
        "N": "393"
    }
  }
}
```

I have exported this DynamoDB data to S3 using the DynamoDB export function.

I can create a table Athena like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
  Item struct <
  orgName:struct<S:string>,
  typeSavings:MAP<string,string>
  >
)
...
```

I can select the items in the table like this:

```
SELECT
    Item.orgname,
    Item.typeSavings
FROM mytable
```

Where the result is:

```
orgname               typeSavings 
-------               --------------------
{s=Aaron's Pets Ltd}  {m={"telecoms":{"n":"50"},"gas":{"n":"393"}}}
```

How can I select items where the `gas` typeSavings are greater than 50?

I can access the orgName simply enough (e.g. `WHERE Item.orgname.s = 'example'`), but I am unsure how to access the map data.

I would be interested in solutions where this is solved at the SQL query step, or at the step where I load the data into Athena. For example, I would be happy to load TELECOMS savings and GAS savings into different columns, at which point the SQL query is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `element_at` to access the map and then `json_extract` to access the json values.

```
SELECT Item.orgname.S as name,
CAST(json_extract(element_at(Item.typeSavings,'m'),'$.gas.n') AS DOUBLE) AS gassavings
FROM mytable
WHERE gassavings > 50
```